# Inconsistent Offset IDs leading to unexpected stops before hitting 1

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon

Why does requesting from some large chats or channels suddenly stop, before eaching offset id 1? Example:

```
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 115
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 13
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 60
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 21
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 369
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 94
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 51
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 33
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 25718 | Total Messages: 10380
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 14077 | Total Messages: 11985
[!] Progress for '1234567890': Offset ID is: 1 | Total Messages: 12254
```

The 1234567890 number indicates a channel id. I am using the following to print the statements:

```
print(f"\r[!] Progress for '{entity.id}': Offset ID is: {offset_id} | Total Messages: {total_messages}", end="", flush=True)
```

Does all chats from channels have an chat message with offset id of 1?